# Prolog beginner - reverse output list

Tags: list, prolog, reverse, fibonacci

I'm a Prolog beginner and I'm looking for a way to reverse the output of this code.

```
fib(N, F) :- fib(N, 0, [1], F).
fib(0, _, A, A).
fib(N, A, [B|Bs], F) :- N1 is N - 1, Sum is A + B, fib(N1, B, [Sum,B|Bs], F).
```

The code calculates the Fibonacci numbers for the value of `N` and prints the result in `F`.

For example `fib(4,X).` produces `X=[5,3,2,1,1]`. What I want is `X=[1,1,2,3,5]` (reversed output).

I can't seem to bring it to this format, and preserve its tail recursive property.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to reverse the list at the end, use `reverse/2`:

```
fib(N, F) :- fib(N, 0, [1], FRev), reverse(FRev, F).
```

If you want to built the list in the reversed order, you would have to rethink the clauses. One solution is to use `last/2` and `append/3` to put new elements at the end of the accumulator, not in front of it.

---

After returning the first solution, Prolog tries to find a second one and you probably get an error:

```
?- fib(5, F).
F = [8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1] ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

That happens because for a goal `fib(0, ...)` Prolog uses the first rule, but creates a choice point and it backtracks to it later. From that point the stack is filled with goals: `fib(-1,...)`, `fib(-2,...)`, etc. None of these will be ever satisfied. You should put a cut operator in the first clause for `fib/4`:

```
fib(0, _, A, A):-!.
```

so it would not try to resatisfy `fib(0,...)` using the second rule.

```
?- fib(5, F).
F = [8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1].
```